# Trying to run a local PHP file from a Javascript, Both locally

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a Javascript that calls a PHP script using AJAX get method. If i run the PHP script externally it works fine and creates the file connections.txt. But with JS it is not working

```
$(document).on("click", "#target2", function(){
var arr = ["one","two","three"];
$.ajax({

                type: 'POST',

                url: 'hello.php',
                data: { name: "saurabh" },
                success : function(msg) {

                    // here is the code that will run on client side after running clear.php on server

                    // function below reloads current page
                    alert(msg);

                }

});

});
```

PHP script :

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('/Users/saurabh/Desktop/connections.txt', 'w');
    echo "Saving file";
    fwrite($fp, "hello");
    //echo $_POST['yourarray']);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you get a 404 or 500 error in the network tab of the developer console?

Comment: Are you wrapping your click bind in a ready function: $(function(){ ... });

Comment: No, i have tested the click and it is working fine. The problem I am facing is with the POST method. I am getting 405 error:

[2015-11-26 00:15:36] ERROR unsupported method `POST'.
localhost - - [26/Nov/2015:00:15:36 CET] "POST /hello.php HTTP/1.1" 405 300
http://localhost:8000/ -> /hello.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'hello.php',
        data: { name: "saurabh" },
        success : function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I just ran that on my localhost, and it works fine. You must be making some mistake with the onclick function. Do it something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#someButton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'hello.php',
            data: { name: "saurabh" },
            success : function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: No, there is no problem with the click button. The problem I am facing is with the Post function. I am getting following error 405 300:

[2015-11-26 00:15:36] ERROR unsupported method `POST'.
localhost - - [26/Nov/2015:00:15:36 CET] "POST /hello.php HTTP/1.1" 405 300
http://localhost:8000/ -> /hello.php